# How to deal with a font that is "larger" than its own characters

Tags: html, css, svelte, sveltekit, line-height

I'm using a font called [Fugaz One](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Fugaz+One) through [@fontsource](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fontsource/fugaz-one). When I put it into an H1, it renders fine. However, the resultant text elements it creates are significantly too tall. If I set the css property `line-height:100%` it renders alongside other text fine, but when it is selected the selection is still too tall. It obscures text above and below it.

**This is the size of the tag when line-height is not set:**
[image: Without line-height set:]

**This is how the selection looks when line height is set:**
[image]

Is there any way to get this font to behave properly? I'd rather not switch, as I'm quite a fan of it.

Also, I have tried setting another font in the H1 tag and it renders fine (expected height of tag).

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem please put a runnable snippet into your question and check that it shows the problem. Put a character with a descender in as well (e.g. f) and you should see that just enough space if being left below the line for its descender.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an inherent property of the typeface. Certain characters go far lower than the baseline, thus the significant empty space below the font.